# How to enable Relteak wireless for a lenovo g40 -30?

Tags: networking, wireless, lenovo, realtek-wireless

I'm unable to see any wireless connection via my Realtek.
this is the info:

```
configuración: driver=pcieport
             recursos: irq:18 ioport:2000(size=4096) memoria:90500000-905fffff
           *-network DESACTIVADO
                descripción: Interfaz inalámbrica
                producto: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
                fabricante: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                id físico: 0
                información del bus: pci@0000:02:00.0
                nombre lógico: wlp2s0
                versión: 00
                serie: 1a:8f:a2:dc:01:20
                anchura: 64 bits
                reloj: 33MHz
                capacidades: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
```

if you please could give the commands to type them in the terminal will be much appreciated. So far I've tried most of the solutions given but no results have I experienced.

I'm new in ubuntu so I'm learning everything, if you could be as specific as possible may improve my chances of starting my wifi connection.

Best regards.

S.

Comment: DESACTIVADO usually means that the hardware switch or key combination is set to disable the wireless radio. Find the key combination and press it.

Comment: @chili555 I've lloked for it: fn+f5 but nothing happens. THank you for writting.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me, i didn't looked as deep as needed. Thank you!
Answer posted by @Pilot6

If you have no other connection to internet, you can temporarily enable wifi by

> sudo modprobe -r ideapad_laptop
>   sudo rfkill unblock all

ciao!